# infinite loop when create infinite scroll using vue.js and laravel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll, infinite

good day; kindly need your support to finalize this issue i try to make infinite scrolle using laravel and vue.js and my proplem is get in finite loop to set request to data base and mu applocation hang up this is my code x component

```
<template>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"><strong> Laravel Vue JS Infinite Scroll - ItSolutionStuff.com</strong></div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div>
                            <p v-for="item in list">
                                <a v-bind:href="'https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/'+item.slug" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</a>
                            </p>
                              <infinite-loading @distance="1" @infinite="infiniteHandler"></infinite-loading>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

    export default {


        mounted() {
            alert()
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        data() {
            return {
                list: [],
                page: 1,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            infiniteHandler($state) {
                let vm = this;

                this.$http.get('/Services?page='+this.page)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    }).then(data => {
                    $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                        vm.list.push(value);
                    });
                    $state.loaded();
                });

                this.page = this.page + 1;
            },

        },
    }
</script>
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/Services', 'ServicesController@Services');
```

[image: looops]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem 1

You are binding to the `distance` property wrong.

### Solution

Instead of 
 `<infinite-loading @distance="1" @infinite="infiniteHandler"></infinite-loading>` 
it should be 
`<infinite-loading :distance="1" @infinite="infiniteHandler"></infinite-loading>`

### Problem 2

In the code, `this.page` is being incremented before `$http.get` is resolved.
This may result in unintentional side effects.

### Solution

As per the example in docs [vue-infinite-loading hacker news example](https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/guide/start-with-hn.html) you should be incrementing the page after data is loaded.